# Docker compose - flyway not connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, java, docker-compose, springboot

I'm trying to dockerize a microservice built with Spring Boot that uses the MySQL database and Flyway.

When I run the microservice through the IDE, the flyway manages to connect with MYSQL, but when I run the command sudo docker compose up there is a Communications link failure and a problem creating the 'flywayInitializer'.

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.12, MySQL 8.0.33, Docker 24.0.1 and Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this connection issue between Flyway and MySQL in Docker Compose? Thanks in advance for the help!

pom.xml

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.12</version>
  <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.7</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
.
.
.
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>     
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  .
  .
  .
</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8000
spring:
  application:
    name: cambio-service
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cambio_service?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: root
  flyway:
    enabled: true
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
ARG JAR_FILE=cambio-service/target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

cambio-db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always    
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: cambio_service
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3308
    ports: 
      - 3308:3308
    expose:
      - 3308
    networks:
      - microservices-network      

cambio-service:
    image: gustavosc1/cambio-service
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: cambio-service/Dockerfile
    environment:
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server:8761/eureka
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.URL: jdbc:mysql://cambio-db:3308/cambio_service?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.USERNAME: docker
      SPRING.DATASOURCE.PASSWORD: root
    ports: 
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - naming-server
      - cambio-db
    networks:
      - microservices-network  

networks:
  microservices-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Logs

```
2023-06-05 09:02:51.484  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 8.5.13 by Redgate
2023-06-05 09:02:51.484  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.5.13
2023-06-05 09:02:51.484  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : 
2023-06-05 09:02:51.581  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-05 09:02:53.322 ERROR [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:147) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at com.gustavo.cambioservice.CambioServiceApplication.main(CambioServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2023-06-05 09:02:53.336  WARN [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

2023-06-05 09:02:54.369  WARN [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] z.r.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter   : Timed out waiting for in-flight spans to send
2023-06-05 09:02:54.380  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-05 09:02:54.506  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-05 09:02:55.424 ERROR [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at com.gustavo.cambioservice.CambioServiceApplication.main(CambioServiceApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:60) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:75) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:147) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.12.jar!/:2.7.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:175) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:48) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar!/:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:150) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:166) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:945) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar!/:8.0.33]
    ... 46 common frames omitted

2023-06-05 09:02:55.430  INFO [cambio-service,,] 1 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.c.s.a.z.ZipkinAutoConfiguration      : Flushing remaining spans on shutdown
Exception in thread "Thread-2" zipkin2.reporter.ClosedSenderException
    at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:265)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.zipkin2.ZipkinAutoConfiguration$1.run(ZipkinAutoConfiguration.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL clients the `localhost` keyword is usually a special beast and implies a connection to the Unix socket rather than a TCP/IP network connection. That Unix socket is only accessible from inside the container where the database server is running.

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html) describes it:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a -`-port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use `--host` or `-h` to specify a host name value of `127.0.0.1`, or the IP address or name of the local server.

I'm not sure if the JDBC driver suffers from the same problem, but it might be worthwhile to change:

```
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cambio_service?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
```

and replace `localhost` with the name of the container running the MySQL database.

Add a suitable name to facilitate the discovery of your MySQL database container in the docker-compose configuration file:

```
cambio-db:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    container_name: my_ideal_container_name
    ...
    networks:
       microservices-network     
          aliases: 
             - my_custom_hostname
    ...
```

and use `my_ideal_container_name` and/or `my_custom_hostname` rather than `localhost` in the JDBC connection string.

(I think that also removes the need to expose port 3308 and allows you to remove the `ports: 3308:3308` option from the docker-compose configuration. )

Comment: In the project's application.yml file, "spring.datasource.url" is defined as "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cambio_service", but in the docker-compose.yml file I had already changed it to "jdbc:mysql: //cambio-db:3308/cambio_service" and it was giving an error.

I created a "container_name: cambio-database" in docker-compose and changed the "spring.datasource.url" to "jdbc:mysql://cambio-database:3308/cambiodb", but unfortunately the error remains.